# UI Slide Out Bar

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos

I have been looking into some options for creating a slide out bar for a Mac application (similar to the iTunes Ping sidebar, has a button that shows/hides it with animation). I recently bought *Cocoa Programming* by Aaron Hillegas and was hoping to find some info on it in there, but no luck. Anyone have a good tutorial or insight on this (for someone new to Cocoa)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For me, it's always helpful to check out sample code. I would look at Brandon Walkin's BWToolkit. Here's a video of his "slide out bar" in action: http://brandonwalkin.com/blog/videos/iCalSplitView.mov

More information about the BSD-licesned source code can be found [here](http://www.brandonwalkin.com/bwtoolkit/).

Comment: Wow! Thank you Reed, appreciate that link I didn't even know this existed (I've been using cocoa for a little over 2 weeks), but I'll check this out thank you